# Javascript grab part of class

Tags: javascript

I have a string

```
<li class="views-row views-row-4 views-row-even views-row-last" style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; float: left; width: 221px; height: 227px; ">  
  <div class="views-field-field-image-fid">
                <span class="field-content"><img class="imagefield imagefield-field_image" width="221" height="215" alt="" src="http://test.com/sites/default/files/1_03_2.png?1316715258"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="views-field-field-pager-item-text-value">
                <span class="field-content">hydraSense®h</span>
  </div>

  <div class="views-field-field-slide-text-value">
                <div class="field-content">hgfhfghgfhgfhhhgf</div>
  </div>
</li>
```

And I want to get the `views-row-4` from `<li class="` how could I get this? My method of splitting by class didn't seem to work.

Comment: I'm just trying to get views-row-4 from the LI class value.

Comment: There is never an excuse for inline styles, fix that first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to get the `li` element itself.  The easiest way is to attach and `id` to the guy then you can use the following to get the DOM element.

```
var element = document.getElementById('theNewId');
var classAttr = element.getAttribute('class');
var second = classList.split(" ")[1];
```

This assumes the "views-row-4" class is always the second one in the class list.  If it's not then we'd need some other criteria by which to search for the value